# Youtube videos rate API does not increase like/dislike counter

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-api-python-client, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to like a video on user's behalf but got stuck in increment of like counter.
Like/Dislike counter is not updating. When a video is rated by api request, I get 200 response which means success according to docs. Also, video is available in user's Liked playlist and the like icon is blue on video but the like/dislike counter does not increase. I've waited for 2 days but the counter is still same. You can see the counter in picture attached. I'm using python 2.7 with google-api-python-client library.

[Screenshot shows blue liked button but counter does not increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW7dw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I already tried to like a video manually and through API, and I get a successful output. I recommend you to try again this process on different/new video and observe if this scenario repeat again.

I use this [`videos:rate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) to increase the **like** of a video, just pass the **video ID** of a video in the `id` parameter and pass a value **like** in the `rating` parameter.

This videos:rate link also has a [PYTHON code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate#examples) that shows you on how to calls the API's `videos.rate` method to set a positive rating for a video.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137281/youtube-api-v3-likes-a-video-but-the-counter-doesnt-increase).

Answer (score 1):

True, Likes/Dislikes counter does not change. Rate appears only for api users who rated video but not for others. This may happen to prevent abuse, no one knows.